# Magento - Retain admin user credentials

Tags: php, magento

I have installed **Magento** Application in my local system and forgot Admin user password.

To reset my admin password through PHPMyAdmin, I have followed these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16983422/3428816

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16983333/3428816

Still I could not access my admin, Is there any other way to retain my admin passoword. Or should I modify any other table?.

Comment: Did you commit after running those queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Change the password using the phpmyadmin by updating the record and setting new password in `md5` format.

Also have a look at below links.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/how-to-reset-magento-admin-passwor